# using keyValue with nested objects Angular

Tags: angular

I have an object that has nested objects that I wish to use to display HTML within a component

```
export const Data: any = {
  obj1: {
    text: `<h3>Title1</h3>
    <p>Some copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copy </p>
    <p>Some copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copy </p>
    <p>Some copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copy </p>
    <p>Some copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copy </p>`,
    title: `Some copy`,
  },
  obj2: {
    text: `<h3>Title2</h3>
    <p>Some copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copy </p>
    <p>Some copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copy </p>
    <p>Some copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copy </p>
    <p>Some copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copy </p>`,
    title: `Some copy`,
  },
  obj3: {
    copy: `<h3>Title3</h3>
    <p>Some copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copy </p>
    <p>Some copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copy </p>
    <p>Some copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copy </p>
    <p>Some copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copySome copy </p>`,
    title: `Some copy`,
  },
};
```

And I'm trying to use keyvalue pipe to display within a loop, taking the title property from the object and using it for the component property binding

```
     <app-comp
        *ngFor="let item of data | keyvalue"
        [title]="item.title"
      >
        <div>{{item.value}}</div>
      </app-comp>
```

I've tried nesting another for loop but can't get it to work

Comment: Your keys look different. But try item.value.title and item.value.copy

Comment: When I do that I get:
` error TS2339: Property 'copy' does not exist on type 'unknown'.

20         <div summary [innerHTML]="item.value.copy"></div>
                                                ~~~~`
And for item.value.title it doesn't resolve to a string value it just show's "item.value.title"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your component ts just paste this:

```
   // before constructor
   items = Object.values(Data);
```

In your html

```
<app-comp
        *ngFor="let item of items"
        [title]="item.title"
      >
        <div [innerHTML]="item.copy"></div>
</app-comp>
```

What we did here is getting all values of Data object which you want here and saved in a property of component.
`Object.values(Data)` will return all the values of Data object.

I hope it will help to solve this problem and future problems related to `Object.values`